# can we use two different queries with CTE table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to make use of CTE table for two queries. when I tried as shown below it gives an error as

> Invalid object name 'cte'.

```
;

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY hours ORDER BY hours
            ) AS rno
        ,personnum
        ,DATE
        ,hours
    FROM datatable
    WHERE personnum = @personnum
        AND hours = @minhrs
    )
INSERT INTO logdata
SELECT PERSONNUM
    ,DATE
    ,HOURS
FROM cte
WHERE rno = 1

UPDATE cte
SET hours = hours + 0.01
WHERE rno = 1
```

insert statement executed but system throws an error at update statement.

Comment: Simple answer:No, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a CTE in more than one statement, their scope is at statement level. What you could do though is make use of the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to capture the rows updated and insert them into your log table:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hours  ORDER BY hours) AS rno, 
            personnum,
            Date,
            hours  
    FROM    Datatable
    WHERE   personnum =  @personnum
    AND     Hours = @minhrs
)
UPDATE  cte
SET     hours = hours + 0.01
OUTPUT  deleted.personnum, deleted.Date, deleted.hours INTO logdata
WHERE   rno=1;
```

If your log table has a foreign key reference then you may need to store the results into a temporary table before inserting them:

```
-- I have had to guess at types here, change them as necessary
DECLARE @tmpLog TABLE (PersonNum INT, Date DATE, Hours INT); 

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hours  ORDER BY hours) AS rno, 
            personnum,
            DATE,
            hours  
    FROM    Datatable
    WHERE   personnum =  @personnum
    AND     Hours = @minhrs
)
UPDATE  cte
SET     hours = hours + 0.01
OUTPUT  deleted.personnum, deleted.DATE, deleted.hours INTO @tmpLog
WHERE   rno=1;


INSERT LogData (personnum, Date, hours)
SELECT  personnum, Date, hours
FROM    @tmpLog;
```

Comment: This is amazing.; it works like a pro. Thank you :)